# Deleting files from a USB drive in windows would still be available to be recovered in MAC?

Tags: windows, mac, usb, recovery

Im not much of an expert in mac iOS so my question might be a naive one but is more of a curiosity. I had a file copied into a USB flash drive. Then after using the drive I deleted the file from the flash drive in a mac. But when I opened the same flash drive in a windows computer, the file was still there. Then after deleting the file again from the flash drive in the windows computer, I checked back in the mac and the file was not there anymore. And this makes me wonder, If i delete a file from a flash drive in windows, can this file still be recoverable in a mac without the use of a file recovery software?

I know that if I dont delete the file from the Mac trash bin, the file might still appear back, but can this happens even if you change to a different Mac?

Comment: This shouldn't have happened. Either you've accidentally deleted a different file, you didn't safely remove the drive or something malfunctioned. Deleting a file shouldn't be machine- or OS-specific under normal circumstances. Unless you can reproduce this, the question isn't answerable because it's assuming abnormal behavior every time.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS and Windows use different mechanisms for the "Delete to Bin/Delete to Recycle Bin" behavior.

MacOS leaves the file in place, but just marks it so that Finder and other MacOS applications show it as being "In the Bin" in stead of the real location.
And since every Mac knows about this MacOS behavior a file put in the Bin on MacOS still is in the Bin when you move the USB drive to another Mac.

WIndows however, if you delete a file to the "Recycle Bin" really MOVES the file to the special hidden folder called "Recycle.bin" which is located in the topmost folder of the drive.

So if you delete a file on MacOS, Windows will still see it in its original location (and Windows happily ignores the MacOS "file is deleted" marker).
If you delete it in Windows then MacOS doesn't see the file anymore, but you can still retrieve it from the RECYCLE.BIN folder, if need be.

In either case the file is only really gone if you empty the Bin/Recycle Bin.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know the way mac and windows treat their deleted files in such detail. so that means that once i delete the file from a windows computer, it shouldnt appear in a mac anymore, unless I use a recovery program? or is the Recycle.bin folder present in the flash drive directly :S this means i need to be very careful when using these 2 OS when deleting files. Thank you!

Comment: @Deltacom The RECYCLE.BIN is a real folder (just hidden) and is accessible from Finder (never tried it myself though, never needed it). But be advised that Windows not always creates a recycle.bin on a removable media. If it doesn't EVERY delete by Windows is a REAL delete requiring a recovery program to undo.

Comment: Can we find source, references somewhere for the described Mac file deletion process? Because I have a hard time following where this "deleted marker" is or what it is.